# Hindi text issue in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, hindi

i was using Hindi fonts in visual studio , it was showing in Hindi fonts, but after few days i don't know why it started showing Hindi text with square boxes , help me please!

Answer (score 0):

possible your windows is updateting, try to install lastest lang service pack
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/60f32ff8-8697-4452-af7d-647439c38433#v1h=tab01

Answer (score 0):

i downloaded Kokila font from google and installed it, then i selected all hindi fonts which were showing as square boxes , and set font for all as Kokila, then Problem got solved!!!

Link:
https://www.wfonts.com/download/data/2016/06/13/kokila/kokila.zip